# CSP Reports being thrown, even after allowing links in whitelist

Tags: magento2, reports, magento2.3.5, csp

I created a new module to allow urls, and have them not make noise about csp.

I have a csp_whitelist file under /etc, and I've added all of my links to it (and cleared the cache), but the warnings are all still there.

I've tried with and without *. before the urls, and that didn't make a difference

here's a sample of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="style-src">
           <values>
               <value id="zendesk-main" type="host">static.zdassets.com</value>
               <value id="fontawesome" type="host">fontawesome.com</value>
               <value id="google-font" type="host">fonts.googleapis.com</value>
               <value id="bootstrap-cdn" type="host">maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm in your same situation :( it's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was removing the prefixes on the urls. For example,

instead of  `<value id="google-font" type="host">fonts.googleapis.com</value>`,

I did  `<value id="google-font" type="host">googleapis.com</value>`

Also, check the console for the errors you're getting, and add them to the list one by one, and make sure that they're in the correct policy block.

```
           <values>
              <value id="google-font>url</value>
           </values>
   </policy>
```